# How to fade in all elements in a header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I fade in all the elements of my `header` when the `window` has fully loaded using the `fadeIn` tag `jQuery` provides?

Relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
 <header class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</header>
```

Comment: if you wan't to fade them in, start making them invisible by default in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke `.fadeIn()` over the element which is having a class header(no need to grab all the elements inside of it) inside `widow`'s `load` event,

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".header").hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Suppose if you want to fadeIn the internal elements for sure then you have to write it like,

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".header > *").hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, it works fantastic, just that I need to add some animations to it. :)

Comment: This answer fades in the header itself, the question asked about fading in elements within the header.

Comment: @DustinPoissant Addressed that too.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how you run a function after the DOM has completely loaded:

```js
$(function(){
  // Code here  
});
```

And you can fade in elements using `.fadeIn`, and you can select all items within the header using `$("header").children()`.

So your complete code looks like:

```js
$(function(){
  $("header").children().fadeIn();  
});
```

If you would like the elements to start "hidden" and then fade in use:

```js
$("header").children().hide();
$(function(){
  $("header").children().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transition on "opacity" property. The advantage is that you can set a lenght (in seconds), a style (ease, ease-in, ease-out, linear, cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n)) and a delay (in seconds) for the effect. Example: `transition: opacity 2s linear 1s;`

```js
function show(){
document.getElementById("header").style.opacity = "1"; 
}
```

```css
#header {
opacity: 0;
background: gold;
-webkit-transition: opacity 3s; /* Safari */
transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

```html
<body onload="show()">
 <header id=header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</header>
</body>
```